# Show that dual space of $R^n$ with norm 3 is equal to the $R^n$ with norm 1.5.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

How can one prove that dual space ($R^n$,$||.||_3$)*= ($R^n$,||.||1.5).
How to go about using the holder's inequality? Any help will be appreciated!

Hint: I know I've to use holder inequality to make the power equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x, y \in \def\R{\mathbf R}\R^n$. $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}$We have by Hölder as $\frac 13 + \frac 1{3/2}  =1$ that
$$ \abs{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i} \le \norm x_3 \cdot \norm y_{3/2} $$
That proves that the map $T \colon (\R^n, \norm\cdot_{3/2})\to (\R^n, \norm{\cdot}_3)^*$ given by 
$$ (Ty)(x) = \sum_i x_i y_i $$
fulfills $\norm{Ty}_3^* \le \norm y_{3/2}$. On the other hand, given $y \in \R^n$, define $x \in \R^n$ by $x_i = \mathrm{sgn}y_i\abs{y_i}^{1/2}$, then
\begin{align*}
  \abs{(Ty)x} &= \abs{\sum_i x_iy_i}\\  
       &= \sum_i \abs{y_i}^{3/2}\\
       &= \left(\sum_i \abs{y_i}^{3/2}\right)^{2/3} \cdot 
           \left(\sum_i \bigl(\abs{y_i}^{1/2}\bigr)^3\right)^{1/3}\\
       &= \norm y_{2/3}\norm x_{3}
\end{align*}
And hence $\norm{Ty}_{3}^* \ge \norm y_{2/3}$.

So, $T$ is a linear isometry, hence one-to-one. As $\R^n$ and $(\R^n)^*$ have both dimension $n$, $T$ is an isometric isomorphism.